# ReferenceError: before is not defined (mocha/protractor)

Tags: reactjs, protractor, mocha.js, e2e-testing

I am using `protractor` with `mocha` in `react` application. When trying to use `before()` or `after()` functions it gives me an error:

```
ReferenceError: before is not defined
```

However using `beforeEach()` or `afterEach()` works perfectly fine.

Here is how I configured `protractor.conf.js`

```
exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  }
};
```

PS. full error:

```
Stacktrace:
    ReferenceError: before is not defined
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/myApp/tests/e2e/routes.js:10:5)
    at normalLoader (/myApp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:160:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/myApp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:173:7)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Function.promise (/myApp/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:650:9)
    at _fulfilled (/myApp/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/myApp/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/myApp/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /myApp/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
    at flush (/myApp/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to manage by adding `framework: jasmine2` to `protractor.conf.js` and instead of `before()` and `after()` I wrote `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()`. 
Now it works as a charm.

The details about that issue can be found in this [gitHub comment](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/103#issuecomment-69627355) by @juliemr

Edit: Typo

Answer (score 2):

This question might be dead though I'll put a little more info in here for those who wonder through. The accepted answer seems confusing to the original question and so we should do go on a little journey to get us back on track.

## What's wrong with the accepted answer?

As @Tomas Dermisek suggests, it should just be a matter of using mocha as the framework. It seems that @Max has decided to use jasmine instead of mocha which is actually an alternative test spec to mocha. That would appear to be why @Max needed to use jasmines `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()` instead of the desired `before()` and `after()` from mocha.

Further evidence of using jasmine is available from the addition of `jasmine2` to the `framework` of the `protractor.conf.js`

## Before we continue there are some things to note between jasmine and mocha

Since someone reading this may have tried the jasmine approach because "it's easier", then you might be using the jasmine `expect` that comes with jasmine out of the box. If you're now looking at actually using mocha it's worth being aware of a couple of nuances that caught me.

1. It seems that protractor interactions like `element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText()` will return a promise. @cnishina pointed out to me today that protractor wraps Jasmine with angular/jasminewd and that's why jasmine appears to work out of the box. This means that in jasmine `expect(element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText()).toEqual('Car search POC');` will work perfectly. If you try and do the equivalent in mocha then it will fail for things like `TypeError` and many other hard to get your head around errors
2. You need a little help from chai and chai-as-promised

   - chai will give you the `expect` and other syntax candy that you would like
   - chai-as-promised enriches your candy with `.eventually` so that you don't need to do `then()` promise resolution all over your tests
   - At the time of writing this the latest chai-as-promised dependency didn't work with chai. Not as-promised anyway (sorry I couldn't resist). These are the versions used by the protractor project with a protractor version I've seen in a working `package.json`

## package.json fragment

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "chai": "~3.5.0",
  "chai-as-promised": "~5.3.0",
  "protractor": "~5.1.0",
  ...
}
```

The following configuration should get you off the ground

## protractor.conf.js

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000, // Timeout of each script
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'  // pattern for your tests
  ],
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/', // URL of your SUT
  capabilities: { 
    'browserName': 'chrome' // name of the browser you want to test in
  },
  directConnect: true, // No need to run selenium server for chrome and firefox
  framework: 'mocha', // The framework we want to use instead of say jasmine
  mochaOpts: { // Some reasonable mocha config
    reporter: "spec",
    slow: 3000,
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 30000
  },
  beforeLaunch: function() { // If you're using type script then you need compiler options
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  },
  onPrepare: function() { // making chai available globally. in your test use `const expect = global['chai'].expect;`
    var chai = require('chai');
    var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    global.chai = chai;
  }
};
```

## tsconfig.e2e.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016"
    ],
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "types":[
      "mocha",
      "chai",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

## Now we've done the plumbing and explaining let's get to the point and answer the OP and demonstrate a working before

An example spec file might look like the spec below and would give this output

```
  search page
I do something in a before!
    √ will display its title
```

It's also worth taking note of the `const expect = global['chai'].expect;` being used in the spec

### e2e/sample.e2e-spec.js

```
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';
import {SearchPage} from './search.po';
const expect = global['chai'].expect;

describe('search page', () => {
  let page: SearchPage;

  before(() => {
    console.log('I do something in a before!');
  });


  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new SearchPage();
  });

  it('will display its title', () => {
    page.navigateTo();

    const title = element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText();
    expect(title).to.eventually.contain('A cool title');
  });
});
```

Comment: To get the same behavior with expect as I did with jasmine, I was able to: `global.expect = function(x) { if (x.then) { return chai.expect(x).eventually; } else { return chai.expect(x); } };`

Answer (score 2):

For other people who get the same error, check your ui configuration. If it's set to tdd before is not supported - your test will throw an exception saying before is not defined. Instead you need to use suiteSetup.

Answer (score 0):

For all those who want to keep using Mocha change the protractor config from

```
frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
```

to

```
framework: 'mocha',
```

It helped me to fix the error "ReferenceError: before is not defined"